# EXTJS4- How to add hyperlink in a grid column?

Tags: extjs4

I want to have link in one column of my grid, like tag named "history" for each row in that column, on click of which will take me to another html page giving details of that row. I also need the info in that row inside the newly opened html page.

Kindly let me know how to do it.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column-cfg-renderer) method on Column to render links, or [template column](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Template) (`Ext.grid.column.Template`).